# BroadcastReceiver on GPS turned off (executes multiple times)

Tags: android, gps, broadcastreceiver

I'm using `<action android:name="android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED" />` to receive a broadcast when the user turns on/off the GPS.

I'm actually interested in showing an alert to the user that report will be sent to the server about him turning off the GPS (By launching an `Activity`), so you can say I'm only interested in knowing when the GPS is changed from ON to OFF.

The issue I'm having is that the `BroadcastReceiver` executes `onReceive()` multiple times (about 2-3 times when turning ON to OFF). **I'm guessing the reason is because it is not only sending a broadcast from gps changes in ON and OFF state, but also from High Accuracy/Batery Saving/Device Only**

My question would be if there is a way to filter even more this calls, so the `BroadcastReceiver` will launch said `Activity` **only when the user changes from ON to OFF** and **not** when changing from high accuracy to batery saving or device only, or any other gps related changes ?

**PD:** I'm new to `BroadcastReceivers`. by reading the documentation, I understand what they are for, but I dont know all the resources you can use them with, like all possible `<category>` tags or all possible `<action>` tags, etc...

Comment: If you have a location listener you could use onProviderEnabled/onProviderDisabled

Comment: mind giving me an example please? callbacks are not being called

Comment: @powder366 Sorry man, I can't recall if I solved this or went for a workaround